# Setting up localhost in proxy service for ArcGIS Javascript API 3.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy

I have a proxy service (DotNet) that works great in my production environment but I can't use it in my development environment. Obviously I really need it to work in my development environment because I don't want to deploy something that doesn't work. I get 404 errors for the resource. This is how my current code sits, but I have tried a couple different things which I will explain in a minute:

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*"
         mustMatch="false"
         logFile="proxyLog.txt"
         logLevel="Warning">
    <serverUrls>
      <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatManagement/HabitatManagement/GPServer"
                 username="xxx"
                 password="xxx"
                 matchAll="true"/>
      <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatMonitoring/HabitatData/MapServer"
                 username="xxx"
                 password="xxx"
                 matchAll="true" />
      <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatMonitoring/HabitatClassification/GPServer"
                 username="xxx"
                 password="xxx"
                 matchAll="true" />
    </serverUrls>
</ProxyConfig>
```

I've tried setting the allowed referrer to my specific local host like this:

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="https://www.mydomain.com/*,"http:/localhost:14906/*"
```

I have also tried this:

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="https://www.mydomain.com/*,"http:/localhost:14906/appName/*"
```

But that doesn't work either. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

This is an example of one of the referring URLs:

> http://localhost:14906/appName/proxy/proxy.ashx?https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatMonitoring/HabitatData/MapServer/2?f=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have my proxy folder under my application in Visual Studio, but when I was running it in a development environment, it was not taking the name of the application into account. I ended up having to edit the proxyUrl property in my JS code to remove the appName and it started working.

Originally I had this:

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
            urlPrefix: "https://www.mydomain.org",
            proxyUrl: "appName/proxy/proxy.ashx"
        });
```

After the fix it became this:

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
            urlPrefix: "https://www.mydomain.org",
            proxyUrl: "/proxy/proxy.ashx"
        });
```

It worked with this code in proxy config:

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*"
     mustMatch="true"
     logFile="proxyLog.txt"
     logLevel="Warning">
<serverUrls>
  <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatManagement/HabitatManagement/GPServer"
             username="xxx"
             password="xxx"
             matchAll="true"/>
  <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatMonitoring/HabitatData/MapServer"
             username="xxx"
             password="xxx"
             matchAll="true" />
  <serverUrl url="https://www.mydomain.com/myserver/rest/services/HabitatMonitoring/HabitatClassification/GPServer"
             username="xxx"
             password="xxx"
             matchAll="true" />
</serverUrls>
```